# Showing custom Annotation View on MKMapView

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I am working on a map application. I am done with fetching locations on certain conditions, showing annotation on map view and displaying my custom callout bubble.

My requirement is to display the annotation pin as follow:

- A Image with rounded corner to display annotation
- On the right top corner of the annotation there will be a red badge kind of view.
- Need to access that red badge view and set text in certain methods.

Now I know I can set Image to the annotation view and make it rounded corner as follow:

```
pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"annotationImage"];
[pinView.layer setCornerRadius:8.0];
[pinView setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

Here `pinView` is an AnnotationView.

Please let me know if I can create a custom view and assign it to pin view so I can get the red badge and set Image as well.

**UPDATE**

I tried lot more things and got succeed to put the view. But the problem is if I use a `MKAnnotationView` object on map I am not able to tap it or call gesture recognizer on it. If I use `MKPinAnnotationView` than I am able to call didSelected method or add a gesture recognizer but I am not able to set a Image on it as it is a Pin Annotation.
Plz let me know if this is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes it is setting Image in imageview and making it rounded corner.. I want to add label etc there. In short need a totally custom view

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the same thing as you were back when you posted this. Were you able to get it to work ? Can you share how did you get a badge to show up on top and also how tapping the image called didSelected method? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to set your Class as `MKMapViewDelegate` and fill this method:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {
 CustomMapAnnotationView *annotationView = nil;

 pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"annotationImage"];
 [pinView.layer setCornerRadius:8.0];
 [pinView setClipsToBounds:YES];

 NSString* identifier = @"CustomMapAnnotation";
 CustomMapAnnotationView *newAnnotationView = (CustomMapAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];

 if(nil == newAnnotationView) {
    newAnnotationView = [[[CustomMapAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation: pinView reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];
 }

 annotationView = newAnnotationView;
 [annotationView setEnabled:YES];
 [annotationView setCanShowCallout:YES];

 return annotationView;
}
```

Thus, you can return a custom Class, subclass of `MKAnnotationView`, and you can add badge now to your custom view.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply but can you plz help me in the implementation of custom annotation like what are the mandatory methods for it and in which method I can add a Custom view like Imageview,Label or button etc..

Comment: I tried to create a Custom Annotation view but it is not allowing me to tap on it. Is there any property I need to set for allow selection?

Comment: Are you adding the setCanShowCallout property as YES?

Comment: Yes.. but I don't want to display a call out. I want to access the annotation in `mapView:didselectAnnotation` method